# Why all ' are converted to &#39; in djnago template?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass some data from django views to django templates where I would like to save this data to javascript variable, but some weird things happen.
If I look data in djnago console I see this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'shape': 'image', 'image': "{% static 'display_network/logos/Router.png' %}", 'label': 'Default gateway'}, {'id': 2, 'shape': 'image', 'image': "{% static 'display_network/logos/VM.png' %}", 'label': 'VM2'}, {'id': 3, 'shape': 'image', 'image': "{% static 'display_network/logos/VM.png' %}", 'label': 'VM3'}, {'id': 4, 'shape': 'image', 'image': "{% static 'display_network/logos/VM.png' %}", 'label': 'VM4'}, {'id': 5, 'shape': 'image', 'image': "{% static 'display_network/logos/VM.png' %}", 'label': 'VM5'}]
```

But when I save data to the javascript variable and print then in the console I get weird result:

```
[{&#39;id&#39;: 1, &#39;shape&#39;: &#39;image&#39;, &#39;image&#39;: &quot;{% static &#39;display_network/logos/Router.png&#39; %}&quot;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;Default gateway&#39;}, {&#39;id&#39;: 2, &#39;shape&#39;: &#39;image&#39;, &#39;image&#39;: &quot;{% static &#39;display_network/logos/VM.png&#39; %}&quot;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;VM2&#39;}, {&#39;id&#39;: 3, &#39;shape&#39;: &#39;image&#39;, &#39;image&#39;: &quot;{% static &#39;display_network/logos/VM.png&#39; %}&quot;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;VM3&#39;}, {&#39;id&#39;: 4, &#39;shape&#39;: &#39;image&#39;, &#39;image&#39;: &quot;{% static &#39;display_network/logos/VM.png&#39; %}&quot;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;VM4&#39;}, {&#39;id&#39;: 5, &#39;shape&#39;: &#39;image&#39;, &#39;image&#39;: &quot;{% static &#39;display_network/logos/VM.png&#39; %}&quot;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;VM5&#39;}]
```

My 'js' code:

```
var devices = "{{ devices }}";        
console.log(devices);
```

All ' are converted to `&#39;` and I dont know why they are converted. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try using `str.normalize().replace ();` and adding you `var` on it ?

Comment: The console can handle logging the original `devices` object just fine, no need to turn it into a string.  If you absolutely need a string, though, try `JSON.stringify(devices)`

Comment: Django assumes it's creating HTML, not JavaScript, so it's encoding special characters.

Comment: Escape the single quotes if you can, this will prevent encoding

Comment: `[{\'id\': 1, \'shape\': \'image\', \'image\': "{% static \'display_network/logos/Router.png\' %}", \'label\': \'Default gateway\'}, {\'id\': 2, \'shape\': \'image\', \'image\': "{% static \'display_network/logos/VM.png\' %}", \'label\': \'VM2\'}, {\'id\': 3, \'shape\': \'image\', \'image\': "{% static \'display_network/logos/VM.png\' %}", \'label\': \'VM3\'}, {\'id\': 4, \'shape\': \'image\', \'image\': "{% static \'display_network/logos/VM.png\' %}", \'label\': \'VM4\'}, {\'id\': 5, \'shape\': \'image\', \'image\': "{% static \'display_network/logos/VM.png\' %}", \'label\': \'VM5\'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark it as safe from auto escaping, then parse from a string.

```
var devices = JSON.parse("{{ devices|safe }}");
```